# Add actionscript with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, flash, actionscript, ffmpeg

Can I add actionscript when I make a swf using ffmpeg?

Say I do:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv file.swf
```

It creates a swf with my video. I now want to check if it is a certain date with actionscript. If it is then I want to display some actionscript code (sprite with textfield saying it has expired and not play video). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you could do is:

1. convert the flv into swf with ffmpeg, just like you wrote in your question
2. create a new flash project, and embed this swf into it

This is how to embed a swf and add it to the stage:

```
[Embed(source="flashfile.swf")]
var swfclass:Class;

//put your expiration check here

stage.addChild(new swfclass());
```

Depending on the scope of your project, you can also do this dynamically using some techniques. There is the Flex SDK and so on to compile swfs from the command line. You can see and start it maybe [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_05.html#150209), or [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html).

Hope this helps.